# SharePoint 2013 List Search Box is missing when added as web part on other page

Tags: 2013

Recently, I'm facing this weird problem with SharePoint 2013 list.

I have a SharePoint List that I used for storing error logs, and I need to embed it as a web part on the other page so that users can easily navigate to error logs without having to click on different menu to see it.
All works fine, except the search box is missing..

Note: In the original list, the search box is fine and displayed well.

I tried to fix it based on this [Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164904/search-box-missing-in-page-with-sharepoint-list) :  Edit Web Part > Miscellanous, but the Display Search Box option is already checked

Here's how it looks like,
[image]

Am I missing something? Is this a SharePoint bugs?

Any suggestion and information would be very appreciated,
Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**: 
Tried to check and compare the html to see if it is a css problem,
unfortunately, it is not.

I go to the default list page of Error Logs and added itself as a webpart (now it has 2 list of itself on the same page), but the search box here is fine,
so this behavior of search box went missing only appear if I add it as web part on other page.

This is where I add the list webpart to itself
[image: Add webpart to itself]

Notice how the div for the search box is properly rendered on this one

```
<div class="ms-csrlistview-controldiv" id="CSRListViewControlDivWPQ2">
```

Then, I checked at the troubled page, the div for the search box is not even rendered properly

```
<div></div>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Is the page a webpart page, or pages under publishing infrastructure, or a self-written aspx page? I tried on a default publishing site and no problem with search box. Maybe you need to cross-check any CSS is hiding the box.

Comment: @Mark It is actually a default document library page (AllItems.aspx) that I customize and add new web part on.

Comment: @Mark Checked it, looks like the div where the search box resides is not even rendered in the troubled page, so I guess this is not a css problem. See my updated question. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how it get fixed,

I just deleted the list webpart and re-add it,
and **now** when I edit web part, the Display Search Box option in Miscellanous tab appears unchecked..(?)
I checked it and save, now the display search box appears!

I dont know why the default value is unchecked though, 
small things like this surely need more attention from Microsoft,

Thanks a lot for your feedback!

Answer (score 2):

If the Style of the View of a list that's a web part on a page is not set to Default (bor, for instance, Shaded instead), then "Display Search Box" will not be available under Miscellaneous in the web part edit control panel.